# Question in Example 2.6.4 Page 57 S. G. Krantz Topology

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

This example is from S. G. Krantz ( A guide to Topology) and I have a question in an example on page 57 in section: Quotient Topology.

[image]

I am unable to understand why this map is 2-to-1 and why 2 points are mapped to same point under π iff a=-b.

Comment: Evety line through the origin intersects the unit sphere in exactly two points (2-yo-1). If one point is $a$, the other point os $-a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $\pi : S^N \to \mathbb P^N$ is $2$-to-$1$ means that there are exactly *two* points $a,b \in S^N$ such that $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$. Notice that the last equation tells us that $b = \lambda a$ for some non-zero real number $\lambda$, but $$1=\|b\| = \|\lambda a\| = |\lambda|\|a\| = |\lambda|,$$ so $\lambda = -1$ since $a \neq b$. Of couse, if $a=-b$, then $a \sim b$ and $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$.

Comment: Perhaps it is better to say that for $a,b \in S^n$ the equation $\pi(a) = \pi(b)$ is equivalent to $\lvert \lambda \rvert = 1$, i.e. $a = \pm b$.

Comment: @azif00 I am not able to get how last equation tells that $b= \lambda a$? Can you please help me with that?

Comment: $a=-b \implies b=\lambda a \ (\lambda = -1)$